# Error using flashplayer in jenkins when running maven-release-plugin. Works when using mvn test

Tags: apache-flex, maven, hudson, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I have a maven 2 job configured in Jenkins, and under the Build I use

```
 clean test release:prepare ...
```

in the **goals** options. Jenkins runs these goals sequenctiallay, and when **test** runs, it prints (and works nice):

```
[WARNING] [LAUNCHER] Using regular flashplayer tests
```

But when it tries to run **prepare** I get,

```
[INFO] [WARNING] [LAUNCHER] Using xvfb-run to launch headless tests
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Failed to launch Flash Player.  Probably java was not able to find flashplayer.
[INFO]      Make sure flashplayer is available on PATH
[INFO]      or use -DflashPlayer.command=${flashplayer executable}
[INFO] Read more at: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/FLEXMOJOS/Running+unit+tests
```

So the same jobs, same jenkins, same job configuration, how can I make it work so that **prepare** also works like the **clean** goal?

I have also tried what the error suggest, that is, putting:

```
 -Dflex.flashPlayer.command=/opt/player_10/flashplayer", "-DflashPlayer.command=/opt/player_10/flashplayer
```